# Collision detection does not return anything

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, collision-detection, sprite, cgrect

I am having some trouble with really quite simple collision detection. Here is my code that I am using at the moment:

```
- (void) update:(ccTime)dt{
NSLog(@"update");
if (CGRectIntersectsRect([self.sprite boundingBox], [self.swat boundingBox])) {
    NSLog(@"detected");
}}
```

'sprite' and 'swat' are subclassed CCSprites that have been declared as a property using:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) CCSprite *swat;
@property (nonatomic, assign) enemyClass *sprite; //enemyClass is a subclass of CCSprite
//note that they have also been synthesized
```

Do I need to change the attributes to get the collision detection working?

I have also tried the following code:

This returns update only:

```
- (void) update:(ccTime)dt{
NSLog(@"update");
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(self.sprite.boundingBox, self.swat.boundingBox)) {
    NSLog(@"detected");
}}
```

This returns 'detected' over and over, even when they are not colliding:

```
- (void) update:(ccTime)dt{
NSLog(@"update");
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(self.sprite.textureRect, self.swat.textureRect)) {
    NSLog(@"detected");
}}
```

**In both sets of code, 'update' is logged, so the update is working correctly, it is just the if statement that is giving me the problem.**

If you could give me any solutions to why this isn't working, or any alternative ways to get it working, I'd be grateful. Thanks.

Comment: Are self.sprite or self.swat nil? You should also NSLog the boundingBoxes and see if they are actually colliding.

Comment: @iBradApps 
The sprite.boundingBox logs {{0,0},{0,0}}
the swat.boundingBox logs {{240,10},{0,0}}
The first set of co-ordinates seem to be the position where they initiate

Comment: Are you NSLogging it in the update method? You yourself should see that they are colliding through NSLogs. Once you confirm that, then you can refactor your code.

Comment: @iBradApps When I log it in the update method, I get things like {{130,30}{0,0}} for the sprites, but the swat always returns {{240,10}{0,0}}, no matter where it is.

Comment: Hmm thats odd. Personally I use Box2D for collision detection because it is easy and more accurate as far as the actual image collision is. I recommend that you do Box2D collision.

Comment: Also maybe ask this question here: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/

Comment: @iBradApps Ok, i'll take a look at box2d, but I wasn't too keen on having to add a new framework to my game. Now for some reason though, the sprite.boundingBox returns null

Comment: Box2D is extremely easy and organized. I only use it for collision detection in my game and it works great. You will need the collision detection classes, make your b2Bodys follow your CCSprites, and then check for the collision in the update loop. I recommend following Ray Wenderlich's tutorial on this since it is very in depth and helpful!

Comment: @iBradApps Ok, i'll give it a shot. Can I incorporate it into my existing project, or do I need to start a new Box2d project?

Comment: Nope, just add it to your already existing project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CGRectContainsRect returns true if second rectangle is *contained* in first. Are you sure you need "contains" check, not "intersects" (CGRectIntersectsRect) check?

Comment: True, CGRectIntersectsRect would be more like what I am looking for, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Try use a `CGRectIntersectsRect()`